# Categorical variables with macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to create categorical variables in sas.  I have written the following macro, but I get an error: "Invalid symbolic variable name xxx" when I try to run.  I am not sure this is even the correct way to accomplish my goal.

Here is my code:

```
%macro addvars;
proc sql noprint;
select distinct coverageid 
into :coverageid1 - :coverageid9999999
from save.test;

%do i=1 %to &sqlobs;
%let n=coverageid&i;
%let v=%superq(&n);
%let f=coverageid_&v;
%put &f;
data save.test;
 set save.test;
%if coverageid eq %superq(&v)
  %then &f=1;
  %else &f=0;
run;
%end; 
%mend addvars;
%addvars;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're combining macro code with data step code  in a way that isn't correct.  %if = macro language, meaning you are actually evaluating whether the text "coverageid" is equal to the text that %superq(&v) evaluates to, not whether the contents of the coverageid variable equal the value in &v.  You could just convert %if to if, but even if you got that to work properly it would be hideously inefficient (you're rewriting the dataset N times, so if you have 1500 values for coverageID you rewrite the entire 500MB dataset or whatnot 1500 times, instead of just once).

If what you want to do is take the variable 'coverageid' and convert it to a set of variables that consist of all possible values of coverageid, 1/0 binary, for each, there are a nubmer of ways to do it.  I'm fairly sure the ETS module has a procedure that just does this, but I don't recall it off the top of my head - if you were to post this to the SAS mailing list, one of the guys there would undoubtedly have it quickly.

The simple way for me, is to do this with entirely datastep code.  First determine how many potential values there are for COVERAGEID, then assign each to a direct value, then assign the value to the correct variable.

If the COVERAGEID values are consecutive (ie, 1 to some number, no skips, or you don't mind skipping) then this is easy - set up an array and iterate over it.  I will assume they are NOT consecutive.

```
*First, get the distinct values of coverageID.  There are a dozen ways to do this, this works as well as any;
proc freq data=save.test;
tables coverageid/out=coverage_values(keep=coverageid);
run;

*Then save them into a format.  This converts each value to a consecutive number (so the lowest value becomes 1, the next lowest 2, etc.)  This is not only useful for this step, but it can be useful in the future in converting back.;

data coverage_values_fmt;
set coverage_values;
start=coverageid;
label=_n_;
fmtname='COVERAGEF';
type='i';
call symputx('CoverageCount',_n_);
run;
*Import the created format;
proc format cntlin=coverage_values_fmt;
quit;

*Now use the created format.  If you had already-consecutive values, you could skip to this step and skip the input statement - just use the value itself;
data save.test_fin;
set save.test;
array coverageids coverageid1-coverageid&coveragecount.;
do _t = 1 to &coveragecount.;
  if input(coverageid,COVERAGEF.) = _t then coverageids[_t]=1;
  else coverageids[_t]=0;
end;
drop _t;
run;
```

Comment: This SAS mailing list you speak of is it this: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/SAS-L
Also, I might have some more questions once I decompose the code you've written here, so if you don't mind, I'll just post them in the comments here.

Comment: I get this error: ERROR: Missing numeric suffix on a numbered variable list (coverageid1-coverageid).
WARNING: Defining an array with zero elements.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, (, ;, _ALL_, _CHARACTER_,
              _CHAR_, _NUMERIC_.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Comment: Ah, forgot - use CALL SYMPUTX not CALL SYMPUT, or the &coveragecount. will have a lot of spaces in it.

Comment: Still working on understanding all that good stuff.  Got to say, coming from T-SQL and C#, SAS is a bit more... convoluted(is the right word?) at this stage in the game, but it's way better on the stat for sure.

Comment: One thing I noticed...how do I go back and figure out what the original coverageid was? I was hoping to have the variable name have the original number it, but if that is not generally how people do it in SAS, that is fine, but whats an easy way to figure out the original id(i know i could just use proc sql and get a list of the ids, then drop it in excel and just add 1,2,3,.... in the next column)

Comment: Not totally sure what you're getting at.  In my code at least the original coverageID is still there.  SAS really is very similar to SQL - so if you can think of it in SQL you can probably think of it in SAS also.  The dataset I produced in coverage_values_fmt will contain the relationship between original coverage ID and the sequential ID, if that's what you're after [dataset==table].

Comment: awesome.  I just did a proc print on the coverage_values_fmt and I understand what you are saying.  Thanks for the help, I learned a ton already.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that doesn't use formats, and *may* be easier to follow.

First, just make some test data:

```
data test;
    input coverageid @@;
    cards;
3 27 99 105
;
run;
```

Next, create a data set with no observations but one variable for each level of `coverageid`. Note that this approach allows arbitrary values here.

```
proc transpose data=test out=wide(drop=_name_);
    id coverageid;
run;
```

Finally, create a new data set that combines the initial data set and the wide one. Then, for each level of x, look at each categorical variable and decide whether to turn it "on".

```
data want;
    set test wide;
    array vars{*} _:;
    do i=1 to dim(vars);
        vars{i} = (coverageid = substr(vname(vars{i}),2,1));
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

The line

```
vars{i} = (coverageid = substr(vname(vars{i}),2));
```

may require more explanation. `vname` returns the name of the variable, and since we didn't specify a `prefix` in `proc transpose`, all variables are named something like `_1`, `_2`, etc. So we take the substring of the variable name that starts in the second position, and compare it to `coverageid`; if they're the same, we set the variable to 1; otherwise it evaluates to 0.

Comment: two things confuse me: 1) why do you sometimes see the `_n_,_name_, or array vars{*} _:; `  what meaning does the `_` hold in sas? 2) both solutions use the input function(is it a function?), but the first solution passes it parameters while the 2nd has no parameters? does it mean different things?

Comment: These are all extremely basic SAS questions, so you are clearly new to SAS. I'd encourage you to start reading some of the documentation. `input` is a function and a statement, which do different things. In this case, it's just to enter data into a data set. `_name_` is just a variable that SAS generates when you run `proc transpose`. `_:` means "all variables that start with "_".